# How do I get the current Editor of an Listitem while ItemUpdating?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, event-handling, synchronous

how can I get the current Editor of an list Item in SharePoint 2010 during ItemUpdating?

Problem is `properties.AfterProperties["Editor"].ToString()` throws and Ecxeption cause it's null. This `properties.ListItem["Editor"].ToString()` is useless cause I get the Editor which made changes the last time.

Any guess how i can Achiev this during the Updating?

Comment: And what is the content of `properties.AfterProperties["Modified_x0020_By"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found out that there is no way to get it this way.

this worked for me: `properties.UserDisplayName`

Answer (score 0):

Check the internal name for the field Modified By

ListItem.ParentList.Fields ["Modified By"]. InternalName

It may be "_Editor" or else.

Comment: The internal name of 'Modified By' is 'Editor' and that is exactly what he tried at first.

Comment: whats the same for a document library? is this same as splist?